# How to set OpenSBI kernel command line argument with Buildroot

Tags: linux, bootloader, riscv, buildroot

How can kernel command line arguments be set when using the OpenSBI bootloader in Buildroot? I want to set the `isolcpus` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think OpenSBI is even able to boot Linux. Typically, there will be a full-fledged boot loader, e.g. U-Boot, that loads Linux and sets the command line.

If OpenSBI is able to load Linux after all, here are a few ways that the command line can be set.

- In the device tree, set the `bootargs` property (at the top level) to the kernel command line you want.
- In the Linux kernel configuration, set `CONFIG_CMDLINE` (and probably enable `CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTEND`).

Comment: This would also work if OpenSBI is loading U-Boot and has itself been started by the U-Boot SPL. It has access to the devicetree passed from the SPL and uses it for stuff like getting the mem-mapped location for core local interrupts